# Play Framework - infinite recursion

Tags: playframework-1.x

I'm getting the error like on https://bugs.launchpad.net/play/+bug/549439. It seems to be an issue with casting an object to a primitive. Is that correct?

I get the error when trying to display a question with its list of answers:
    `<ul>
      #{list question.answers, as:'answer'}
        <li>&{answer.content}</li>
      #{/list}
    </u1>`

I changed to answer.content from answer thinking the issue arose due to casting, but I get the same error.

Here's the stack trace:

Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /showQuestion?qid=1

Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Application.java around line 43)
RuntimeException occured : java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:231)
    at Invocation.HTTP Request(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at play.templates.BaseTemplate.throwException(BaseTemplate.java:93)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.internalRender(GroovyTemplate.java:257)
    at play.templates.Template.render(Template.java:26)
    at play.templates.GroovyTemplate.render(GroovyTemplate.java:187)
    at play.mvc.results.RenderTemplate.(RenderTemplate.java:24)
    at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:660)
    at play.mvc.Controller.renderTemplate(Controller.java:640)
    at play.mvc.Controller.render(Controller.java:695)
    at controllers.Application.showQuestion(Application.java:43)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeWithContinuation(ActionInvoker.java:548)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:502)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:478)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invokeControllerMethod(ActionInvoker.java:473)
    at play.mvc.ActionInvoker.invoke(ActionInvoker.java:161)
    ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:2882)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.expandCapacity(AbstractStringBuilder.java:100)
    at java.lang.AbstractStringBuilder.append(AbstractStringBuilder.java:390)
    at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:119)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:106)
    at play.data.binding.Unbinder.unBind(Unbinder.java:110)

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not related to the linked bug, you have a typo in your code. Fix your code to:

```
... <li>${answer.content}</li> ...
```

The `&{…}` syntax is used for fetching translation labels from `messages` file

**BTW** Asked you before: try to use tags like `playframework-1.x` or `playframework-2.0` for all questions, it helps a lot for people who wants to help you.

Comment: Still getting the same problem!

Comment: How about: `Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Application.java around line 43)` what's there ? (BTW tip with replacing `&` to `$` is still valid)

Comment: Can you publish your **whole** code somewhere ? ie. at github

Comment: line 43: render(question). Sure, i'll put it up on github and post a link to the repo.

Comment: I signed up with git, got everything set up. I'm not able to find directions on how to push my existing play project into a git repo. Could you point me to a link or give a brief description on how to do it?

Comment: There's useful 'help' section on github, there are also samples how to enable git support for existing source: http://help.github.com/create-a-repo/ . If you're not familiar with git, make a **copy of the folder** just to be secured in case of some mistake :)